# Where are we supposed to store user-independent preferences files on MacOS?

Tags: macos, filesystems, preferences, macos-high-sierra

Where are we supposed to store user-independent preferences files on MacOS? For user-specific files, it's /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Appname/, and you'd think for user-independent files it'd be /Library/Application Support/Appname/. However, in modern versions of MacOS there is apparently no way to write to this folder without doing some stupid obtuse launching of a separate "priviledged task" process. Surely Apple has given us a place where we can easily write data that can be read/written by any user on a system? WHY ARE APPLE AND MS BOTH MAKING THIS SO FREAKING DIFFICULT LATELY!?

Comment: Having system-wide configuration data writeable by any unprivileged user poses a security risk and goes against the idea of sandboxing of applications that both MS and Apple implement in their OSes.

Comment: It is stupid-easy for them to make a secure place where applications can read and write that is user-independent but not necessarily application-independent. It's user-hostile not to do so.